# Is it possible to run 2x GeForce 7600 GS in one machine?

Tags: motherboard, nvidia-geforce

Is it possible to run 2x GeForce 7600 GS in one machine?

Comment: Yes it is but I would recommend just buying a new graphics card... These are so outdated that you wouldn't see much of a performance increase. Also you have to make sure your motherboard will allow for SLI video card configuration

Comment: what slot do graphics card usually come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The NVIDIA® SLI™-Ready GeForce® 7600 graphics processing units (GPUs)"
This means that you can use 2 or up to 4 SAME GRAPHICS CARD in a bundle. But you WONT get double the performance, because the both graphics card have to load the same textures. There will be boost in preformance but not as high as double. I will take a guess but you will need atleast 2 PCIe x8 or x16 on your Motherboard to run this graphics cards for gaming purpose. You will also need a a bridge connector that comes with a SLI ready graphics card. I hope I helped

Comment: what is a bridge connector